# How to create Mach-O symbol aliases in NASM?

Tags: macos, nasm, symbols, mach-o

I have an assembly file that exports two functions. The function names are `NASM_RDRAND_GenerateBlock` and `NASM_RDSEED_GenerateBlock`. The symbols lack the leading underscore decoration. The file is assembled with NASM.

In the C/C++ code, the symbol names are declared as `extern "C"` to avoid mangling. Linking under Linux and Cygwin works as expected. Linking under OS X fails with:

```
...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NASM_RDRAND_GenerateBlock", referenced from:
      RDRAND::GenerateBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in libcryptopp.a(rdrand.o)
  "_NASM_RDSEED_GenerateBlock", referenced from:
      RDSEED::GenerateBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in libcryptopp.a(rdrand.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I want to create an alias such that `_NASM_RDRAND_GenerateBlock = NASM_RDRAND_GenerateBlock` so Apple's linker can link to the symbol. Microsoft's [PE format and MASM allow it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654356/608639), but I'm not sure if Apple and Mach-O have similar facilities.

My first question is, does the Mach-O file format support symbol aliases?

If so, then my second question is, how do I tell NASM to create the alias? Or what do I need to do in NASM to create a symbol alias?

---

Here are the command used to build the object files:

```bash
nasm -f macho32 rdrand.S -DX86 -g -o rdrand-x86.o
nasm -f macho64 rdrand.S -DX64 -g -o rdrand-x64.o
```

Here is the [assembler file](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/rdrand.S).

Comment: Add your nasm command line you are using to compile the assembly file to the question. Also, you are recompiling the C/C++ file on OSX as well? It is likely you need to use the `--prefix _` command options on NASM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `macOS` you can use the type `N_INDR` to alias another symbol.

From */System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/mach-o/nlist.h*:

> If the type is N_INDR then the symbol is defined to be the same
>   as another symbol.  In this case the n_value field is an index into
>   the string table  of the other symbol's name.  When the other symbol
>   is defined then they both take on the defined type and value.

There's also a tool `indr`, which you can compile that might help in the case of using assembly:

↳ https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-895/misc/indr.c